# Simulating an apk file using java swing for using it in my desktop

Tags: java, android, swing, simulation, ui-virtualization

I have a list of apk files which i must have the facility to use it inside a java swing application. Like when i press a tab, it must simlaute the apk file1, another tab for 2. like wise.

In a better way, I need to virtualize the apk in java swing to use it as my desktop application for my comfort.

Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't.

Android applications requires a lot of dependencies that are not available in the *classic* Java environment.

However, you can run Android applications on your desktop through some emulators such as [Andy](http://www.andyroid.net/) or [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any open source tool available which I can modify to my comfort?.

Comment: Not yet *or that I know about*